# awk to update field based on if statements except if keyword is in field

Tags: awk

The `awk` below works great for `input1` (when all the required field are present and have values). The `Exception` fied is updated according to the `if` statements in the `awk`.
It does not for `input2` or `input3` (where all the required fields are present but the values are not expected).  The only two fields that can not have a numerical value in them are `Barcode2` and `Barcode3`. Most of the time they will, but when they are not present the word`missing` is the value. My question is when either of these two fields or one of them is `missing` then that field can be be skipped or not used in the `if` statements. I am not sure how or where to do that. Thank you :).

**input** `tab-delimited` ---Barcode2 and Barcode3 are "missing"

```
Barcode1    Barcode2    Barcode3    NoBarcode   Exception
38774136    missing     missing     0.89
```

**script**

```
awk '
BEGIN { # Set input and output field separator:
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}

NR == 1 {# Search line 1 of file
    # Create array to tranlate needed field headers to field numbers:
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    next
}

{
    if($f["Barcode1"] < 20000000 ||
       $f["Barcode2"] < 2000000 ||
       $f["Barcode3"] < 2000000) {
        $f["Exception"] = "Failure due to low barcode reads"
    }
    else {
        $f["Exception"] = "Pass"
    }
    print
}
' input
```

**current output for input** `tab-delimited` should be Pass in Exception as the missing fields are not used

```
Barcode1    Barcode2    Barcode3    NoBarcode   Exception
38774136    missing     missing     0.89     Failure due to low barcode reads
```

**desired output for input** `tab-delimited` should be Pass in Exception as the missing fields are not used

```
Barcode1    Barcode2    Barcode3    NoBarcode   Exception
38774136    missing     missing     0.89        Pass
```

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your current output as well as required output from your sample inputs. Verbal descriptions almost always lead to "oh, and I meant X1, not X" chain of discussions in comments. Good luck.

Comment: I added the current output to the post. Thank you :).

Comment: you're getting there. I see 2 sets of `current output for input2/3`, I don't want to have to guess which is the desired output. Please update your Q. Also, it seems like your problem is related to `&&`ed conditional logic, which pattern matching blocks like `NR>1{ ...}` don't help so much with. Do you know about the more general construct that processes all lines, ie.e `awk -F, '{ if (cond1 && cond2 && .... || altCond ....){ do stuff } else if (cond7 && cond8) { other stuff} } else { more stuff}}' file` ? Good luck.

Comment: I edited the post cleaning up the output and trying to be more concise with the question. @Shelter I was not aware of that construct... Thank you :).

Comment: arg, I know this must be frustrating for you, but now you're removed too much from your Q. We need the minimal amount of sample data, code, current output, expected output and error messages so we can copy/paste into our terminal windows and reproduce your problem in less that 1 minute. As your `...$f["Barcode1"] < 20000000 || $f["Barcode2"] < 2000000 || $f["Barcode3"] < 2000000)` test doesn't seem to be working as you expect, edit your Q with sample data with 1 record that should pass that test, and 1 record that will fall thru to the `else` block. . . .

Comment: While we need the setup for headers, but do you really need 9-10 columns to see how this works? Reduce your sample to 4-5 fields (you can still test 3 fields at once). and you may figure out your problem on your own. If not, post your revised current output and the expected output and we'lll get this to work for you. Stick with it, you're almost there (this is building character! ;-)! . Good luck.

Comment: Thank you both I took a stab at the indenting and am in the process of reading Effective Awk Programming as well... I am learning a lot but its a work in process. I think that is all I need to add to my script.... how does the indenting look?  Thnak you :).

Comment: Please do, I learn a great deal from your help :).... this is a great site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just asking how to only do a comparison on a field if it doesn't contain the word "missing"? Instead of:

```
if ( $f["Barcode1"] < 20000000 ||
     $f["Barcode2"] < 2000000  ||
     $f["Barcode3"] < 2000000 )
         $f["Exception"] = "Failure due to low barcode reads"
```

do this:

```
if ( ($f["Barcode1"] != "missing" && $f["Barcode1"] < 20000000) ||
     ($f["Barcode2"] != "missing" && $f["Barcode2"] < 2000000)  ||
     ($f["Barcode2"] != "missing" && $f["Barcode3"] < 2000000) )
         $f["Exception"] = "Failure due to low barcode reads"
```

Also note the use of white space and indentation to make code more readable!

I highly recommend you read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as it will not only teach you the awk language but will help with general programming fundamentals like `if`, `&&`, `||`, etc.